# what do you mean by base class reference or derived class reference?

Tags: c++, class, casting, reference

I am confused about **base class reference** and **derived class reference** in the context of upcasting and downcasting.

In the following code, what is the use of `&ref`? In the [reference](https://www.javatpoint.com/upcasting-and-downcasting-in-cpp), it was marked as a **base class reference**, to which a **derived class obj** was assigned.

What is the concept behind this?

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
class Base  
{  
    public:  
        void disp()  
    {  
        cout << " It is the Super function of the Base class ";  
    }  
};  
  
class derive : public Base  
{  
    public:  
        void disp()  
        {  
            cout << "\n It is the derive class function ";  
        }  
      
};  
  
int main ()  
{  
    // create base class pointer  
    Base *ptr;  
      
    derive obj; // create object of derive class  
    ptr = &obj; // assign the obj address to ptr variable  
      
    // create base class's reference  
     Base &ref = obj;   
    // Or  
    // get disp() function using pointer variable  
      
    ptr->disp();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: do you know what a reference is? do you know what base classes and a derived classes are?

Comment: @bolov yes sir I know about this terms

Comment: then what's the confusion? A base class reference is a reference of a base class type.

Comment: *"What is the concept behind this?"* -- could you expand upon what you mean by "this"? I would take "this" to mean "marked as a base class reference, to which a derived class obj was assigned" but the concept behind that is what was stated: a derived class object is assigned to a base class reference. Maybe explain why this seems wrong to you? Otherwise, you might have to wait until someone guesses what is on your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is not clear what you're asking, i will try to clear some basics regarding this topic.

First, a **reference** refers to some other object. A reference is not an object by itself. So lets looks at some examples:

```
int n = 10;
int &r = n; // Here r is a reference to an int object
```

Similarly in your code snippet, when you wrote:

```
derive obj; //obj is an object of type derive
Base &ref = obj;  // ref is bound to the Base part of derive
Base *ptr = &obj; // ptr points to the Base part of derive
```

In the above example, there are 2 important things to note:

1. Because a derived object contains **subparts** corresponding to its base class(es), we can use an object of a derived type as if it were an object of its base type(s). In particular, *we can bind a base-class **reference or pointer** to the base-class part of a derived object* as done above. This conversion is called **derived-to-base** conversion.
2. The **static type** of object named `ptr` is `Base*`. While the **dynamic type** of the same object `ptr` is `derive*`. So the static and dynamic type differs.

Also, note that we are able/allowed to write:

```
Base *ptr = &obj;
```

because as [**$11.2/5 states -**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/class.access.base)

> If a base class is accessible, one can implicitly **convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base class**.

Now coming back to your question:

> what is the use of &ref?

```
class Base  
{  
    public:  
        virtual void disp()  //VIRTUAL kewword USED HERE
    {  
        cout << " It is the Super function of the Base class ";  
    }  
};
```

If in your code snippet, the method `disp()` was **virtual** as shown in the above modified snippet, then we could've used `ref` and `ptr` to call the method `disp()` of the `derive` class. This is because:

According to [virtual function documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-virtual-functions-c)

> a virtual function is a member function you may redefine for other derived classes, and can ensure that the compiler will call the redefined virtual function for an **object of** the corresponding **derived class**, even if you call that function with a **pointer** or **reference** to a base class of the object.

So when we write:

```
ref.disp(); //this calls the derive class method disp() at runtime
ptr->disp(); //this calls the derive class method disp() at runtime
```

The [result](https://onlinegdb.com/pJdaFihOj) of the above is that the derive class' function named `disp` is called at **run-time** and we see `It is the derive class function` printed on the console.

So basically the use is that we can decide at runtime which method(whether Base's or derive's) to call.

Check out the program's output [here](https://onlinegdb.com/pJdaFihOj).